# Python Seaborn: reducing the size of x-axis labels only

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn, heatmap

I am trying to create a heatmap. I noticed that x-axis label does not show completely due to large size.

[image]
 I tried to reduce the size of the x-axis label by using following commands:

```
ax = plt.axes()
sns.set(font_scale=0.8)
plt.rcParams["axes.labelsize"] = 0.5
sns.heatmap(equip_df.set_index('Zone'), annot=True,ax=ax)
ax.set_title('Year 2016')
plt.show()
```

But it did not reduce the size of x-axis label. Could anyone guide me how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Get the labels with `locs, labels = plt.xticks()`
- Set the font with `b.set_xticklabels(labels, size = 4)`

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("year", "month", "passengers")

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 8))
b = sns.heatmap(flights)

# get the labels
_, labels = plt.xticks()

# set the label size
b.set_xticklabels(labels, size = 4, rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]